# Setting up a jQuery UI Slider to control a variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have set up a an array that looks like so:

```
coolnessGraph = new Array(
    [($pink),'Mr. Pink'],
    [200,'Mr. White'],
    [230,'Mr. Brown'],
    [300,'Mr. Black' ]
```

Instead of entering an integer that correlates with the name in my array I would like to replace the integers with variables (i.e. `$pink` in lieu of `100` or whatever) and have the variable be controlled through a jQuery UI Slider. I have never used one of these before and would love some pointers on how to take the UI Slider code below and have it control my `$pink` variable.

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value + " %");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide us with html that matches your slider code?  [A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would also be quite useful.  Make sure you add the code to the question tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would change the array to a JSON object and work from that:

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2ytU/)

```
$(function() {
  var coolnessGraph = {};
  coolnessGraph.MrPink = 100;
  coolnessGraph.MrWhite = 200;
  coolnessGraph.MrBrown = 300;
  coolnessGraph.MrBlack = 400;

  $("#value").text(coolnessGraph.MrPink);

  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        coolnessGraph.MrPink = ui.value;
        $("#value").text(coolnessGraph.MrPink);
    }
  });
});
```

and the html

```
<div style="padding: 15px">
  <div id="slider-vertical"></div>
  <br />
  <div id="value">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ swatkins, first of all thank you for your time and input. On an independent level that would work and be a good way to go. The reason that I am using an array w/ variables is because this will in turn drive a bar graph that collects it's data from an array.                    coolnessGraph = new Array(
    [($pink),'Mr. Pink'],
    [200,'Mr. White'],
    [230,'Mr. Brown'],
    [300,'Mr. Black' ]

                  
           );
  $("#ROIchart").jqBarGraph({
            data: coolnessGraph, )}

Comment: Well, you can set a variable in the array, but it won't update as the slider updates. You'll have to rebuild that array and reset the graph with each update. Here's an update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K2ytU/3/

Comment: Good, to know it's sounding like I can't achieve what I'm trying to do the way I'm trying to do. I set up what I'm working with in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swordfish0321/kQhrr/ ...not sure how I would implement your function with my bar graph function.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle that might help you to sort it out. When you move and stop the slider, the graph is generated. When you move and stop it again, the graph is regenerated. http://jsfiddle.net/kQhrr/2/

Comment: So what if I decided to set a variable to equal an HTML element in lieu of the slider? eg. the variable (which directs data to my array) and set it to equal an HTML string. var ROI1 = '<span id="one"></span>'; This block element with the id of one has data from a function dumped into it. I turn that data into a variable that I can place in my array...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up an array with `($pink)` it only make the default value, so if you want to change the value inside the array you must assign it again when you change the value of slider.

Instead of doing this, you can try to use your destination as a variable control your array.

```
$Mr_pink = coolnessGraph[0];
```

Then you can assign it while it slide.

```
$("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: $(pink),
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(Mr_pink)[0] = ui.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: So what if I decided to set a variable to equal an HTML element in lieu of the slider? eg. the variable (which directs data to my array) and set it to equal an HTML string. var ROI1 = '<span id="one"></span>'; This block element with the id of one has data from a function dumped into it. I turn that data into a variable that I can place in my array...any thoughts?